# Sequelize error in AWS Lambda "sequelize.authenticate(...).then(...).catch(...).done is not a function"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

While testing an AWS Lambda (built by Serverless AWS SDK), I receive this error when it runs 'handler.js'

Full text of error:

```
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "sequelize.authenticate(...).then(...).catch(...).done is not a function",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: sequelize.authenticate(...).then(...).catch(...).done is not a function",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/handler.js:30:4)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)",
    "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)",
    "    at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)"
  ]
}
```

Code from handler.js:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    port: "3306",
    dialect: "mysql",
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    }
  }
);

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("DATABASE CONNECTED! ");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .done(); ## NOTE THIS IS LINE 30 of handler.js
```

Comment: What is .done()? Get rid of it.

Comment: It is as the error says it is. `.done()` is not a property of a Sequelize promise.